# Como encontrar blocos de caracteres repetidos dentro de uma string?

Tags: python, string

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade e para poder continuar preciso pegar uma mensagem que foi dada e descobrir se tem blocos de caracteres repetidos dentro dessa mensagem e qual é o bloco. Exemplo: mensagem= banana; sei que tem um bloco de caracteres 'na' que se repete duas vezes na mensagem. Eu saberia achar um caractere repetido, mas um conjunto de caracteres não faço ideia.

Comment: O que vc já tentou?

Comment: Até agora eu pensei em pegar uma fatia da string e ir comparando com ela toda. Por exemplo, eu pego uma fatia inicial de três caracteres e comparo pra ver se encontro algo que corresponda, se sim, comparo novamente mas com uma fatia maior (de 4 caracteres), até que a comparação não retorne mais nada. Mas isso eu pensei considerando que algum bloco de caracteres no início da mensagem irá se repetir.

Answer (score 0):

Credito que com a biblioteca de expressões regulares "re" você consiga resolver esse seu problema, caso você queira alguma ajuda com o código você poderia passar exemplos de entrada que será passada e o que você espera que seja a saida.